# Get all writable OIDs from snmpwalk

Tags: snmp

It's easy to do a `snmpwalk` to get a list of all the valid OIDs for a system.  How can I tell which of those OIDs are read only, and which are writeable?

```
$ snmpwalk -v1 -c testing 256.256.256.256
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Testing Device
DISMAN-EVENT-MIB::sysUpTimeInstance = Timeticks: (1160403) 3:13:24.03
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this script https://github.com/DanNegrea/SNMP-Write-Check

It first uses snmpwalk and then performs snmpset for each OID